# React 16.6.3 Context API contextType not being set

Tags: reactjs

I have updated my local create-react-app to 16.6.3 (react and react-dom).  I am trying to get an example of the contextType to work.  Where I want to be able
access the context from componentDidMount method.  When I use the .Consumer part it works, but that is only within the render, I need to be able to get it and set some logic with it.

I have an example on codesandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/w08v196jww

I would expect the `green.js` class to be able to get the context from `Green.contextType = AppContext` and then be able to access it via the `this.context` approach.  but the context always returns an empty object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like this problem is caused by a circular dependency. Extracting `AppContext` to a separate file should fix your issue.

Here is how it looks with your example:
https://codesandbox.io/s/l49yw1ow4z